# Mark ticks in latex in matplotlib

Tags: python, latex, matplotlib

In a plot in matplotlib I specially want to mark points on the x-axis as pi/2, pi, 3pi/2 and so on in latex. How can I do it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `plt.xticks` command can be used to place LaTeX tick marks. See this [doc page](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/usetex.html) for more details.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cos = np.cos
pi = np.pi

# This is not necessary if `text.usetex : True` is already set in `matplotlibrc`.    
mpl.rc('text', usetex = True)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
t = np.linspace(0.0, 2*pi, 100)
s = cos(t)
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xticks([0, pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2, 2*pi],
           ['$0$', r'$\frac{\pi}{2}$', r'$\pi$', r'$\frac{3\pi}{2}$', r'$2\pi$'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you're doing this to an axis handle, then you need two separate calls: one to `set_xticks` and another to `set_xticklabels`. For example, `ax.set_xticks([0, pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2, 2*pi])` followed by `ax.set_xticklabels(['$0$', r'$\frac{\pi}{2}$', r'$\pi$', r'$\frac{3\pi}{2}$', r'$2\pi$'])`.

Comment: @AaronVoelker: Another way to do it is `ax.set(xticks=[0, pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2, 2*pi],
       xticklabels=['$0$', r'$\frac{\pi}{2}$', r'$\pi$', r'$\frac{3\pi}{2}$', r'$2\pi$'])`.

Comment: I guess most of the time people that try to use TeX in matplotlib fail because they forget to wrap the TeX in `$` or because they forget to escape the backslashes (or use raw string literall `r''`)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to update the `pyplot rcParams`, although this might be rather a hack than a legitimate way.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cos = np.cos
pi  = np.pi

params = {'mathtext.default': 'regular' }  # Allows tex-style title & labels
plt.rcParams.update(params)

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
t   = np.linspace(0.0, 2*pi, 100)
s   = cos(t)
plt.plot(t, s)

ax.set_xticks([0, pi/2, pi, 3*pi/2, 2*pi])
ax.set_xticklabels(['$0$', r'$\frac{\pi}{2}$', r'$\pi$', r'$\frac{3\pi}{2}$', r'$2\pi$'])
plt.show()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDxff.png)